# What is $d \pi (x, y)$ in the Kantorovich formulation of transport map?

Tags: measure-theory, optimization, optimal-transport

The problem of optimal transport (Monge-Kantorovich problem) in Kantorovich formulation looks as follows:

> Let there be a metric space $(E, D)$. And we have to transort a certain amount of mass from the initial distribution, to the final distribution of points. And there is cost function associated with the transport:
> $$
> C(x, y) : E \times E \rightarrow R. 
> $$
> And $\mu, \nu \in P_2(E)$ are measures to be transported. So we have to find a map $\pi(x, y) \in P(E \times E)$, such that minizes the cost function:
> $$
> \mathrm{inf} \int_{E \times E} C(x, y) \ d \pi(x, y) 
> $$
> With the constrains:
> $$
> \int_E \pi(x, y) dy = \mu(x) \qquad \int_E \pi(x, y) dx = \nu(y)
> $$

And my question is, what does the $d \pi (x, y)$ denote in the present case? Is it some measure on a functional space? Integration overall all possible mappings, subject to a certain constrains?

I would be grateful for comments and suggestions

Comment: $\pi$ is a measure on $E\times E$, not $\pi(x,y)$. Then $\int \dots d \pi(x,y)$ denotes integration with respect to this measure. The arguments $(x,y)$ are for clarity to indicate with respect to which variables will be integrated.

Comment: Besides the observation by @daw that $π$ is a measure on $E×E$,  it is also important to understand the boundary
conditions which should actually say that $μ$ and $ν$ are the *marginal measures* for $π$,  in the sense that
$μ(A)=π(A×E)$ and $ν(A)=π(E×A)$,  for every Borel subset $A⊆E$.  Sometimes these measures are absolutely continuous wrt
some other measure, and then you may speak of densities  (the so called Radon-Nikodym derivative) but, for the
purpose of understanding the main idea behind Kantorovich's formulation,
it is best to think of  them as actual  measures.

Comment: @Ruy thanks for the clarification!

Comment: what is the meaning of $E$ in the dimensions $E\times E$? Instead, why not use the word "matrix" for the cost matrix $C$ and the transport matrix $\pi$?

Comment: @develarist, $E$ is a metric space.  Although it makes sense to call $C$ a matrix (as is the case for any function of two variables), when $E$ is not discrete there is no sensible way in which $\pi$ can be interpreted as a matrix.

Comment: @develarist, actually in the lectures, I am reading, there is a discrete and continuous case. It is matrix for discrete distributiion

Comment: @Ruy but the python OT package POT does calculate $\pi$ as a matrix https://pythonot.github.io/quickstart.html

Comment: @develarist, as I said, when $E$ is discrete, say finite, then measures on $E\times E$ may be viewed as a matrix but otherwise this is impossible.

Comment: thanks, other than that, is there a source that goes over the maths of calculating the derivative of the $\pi$ matrix of the discrete case, i.e. the **matrix calculus** behind optimal transport?